# How to keep the same session beetween different activities/fragments in Android?

Tags: android, mysql

I am building an Android App that has a Login and Sign Up and I'm using MySql to save the users. I have a table for users and one for posts in my database and id_post is a foreign key in my users table to create a connection between them.
How can I implement this connection after logging in Android?
 In my Login Activity I start a session with SessionManager. How can I put this same session in the other activites? would it be enough?

Comment: just save your session value in shared prefereces and you can use it anu where in the application by retrieving its value. At the time of session value update just update the session value in the same shared preference.

Comment: @RahulSharma the session value updates automatically when a new user logs in? And if i retrieve its value, it will happen by default that the app recognizes dhe user?

Comment: yes. at the time of login just update its value

Answer (score 0):

first create:

```
public class App extends Application {

SessionManager sessionManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sessionManager=new SessionManager(this);
}

public SessionManager getSessionManager(){
    return sessionManager;
}


}
```

call session in new activity:

```
App app;

app = ((App)getApplicationContext());


if (sessionManager==null){
    sessionManager=app.getSessionManager();
}
```

add manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".App">
</application>
```